# Convert HEX value to CHAR on DB2

Tags: sql, db2

In connection with data replication from `SQL Server` to `DB2` I have the following question:

On `DB2` I have a table containing (for simplicity) two columns: `COL1` and `COL2`.

`COL1` is defined as `CHAR(20)`. `COL2` is defined as `CHAR(10)`.

`COL1` is replicated from SQL by converting a string into hex, e.g. `"abcdefghij"` to `"6162636465666768696A"` or `"1111111111"` to `"31313131313131313131"` by using the following SQL query:

```
CONVERT(char(20), cast(@InputString as binary) 2)
```

where `@InputString` would be `"abedefghij"`.

In other words COL1 contains the hex value, but as a string (sorry if the wording is incorrect).

I need to convert the hex value back to a string and put this value into `COL2`.

What should the SQL query be on `DB2` to do the convertion? I know how to do this on `SQL Server`, but not on `DB2`.

Note: The reason the hex-value is not pre-fixed with `"0x"` is because style 2 is used in the `CONVERT` statement.

Comment: Solved my problem, kind of. Turns out that a column defined as BINARY on SQL Server will be replicated correctly to a column defined as VARCHAR for BIT on DB2. Would still like to know the answer to the above, if anyone should have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select hex('A') from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

returns 41.
and

```
select x'41' from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

gives you 'A'. So you can put that in a `for` loop and loop through each pair of hex characters to arrive at your original string. Or you can write your own unhex function.

Taken from <s>dbforums.com /db2/1627076-display-hex-columns.html</s> (edit Nov 2020: original source link is now a spam site)

Answer (score 6):

DB2 has built-in encoding/decoding.

For OPs question, use....

```
select CAST(ColumnName as char(20) CCSID 37) as ColumnName from TableName where SomeConditionExists
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_introcodepage.dita

Comment: Thank you!! Wish I could give you more than one upvotes :D

Comment: SQL0622N  The clause "CCSID <integer>" is invalid for this database.  
SQLSTATE=56031

Answer (score 3):

This is one of most close topics to subject of my problem:

I have lost 2 days to figure out how to migrate XML files stored in DB2 BLOB field using SQL Developer.
(Yes, migrating to and doing the queries from SQL Developer - we are migrating data to Oracle from DB2, so we were using this tool)!

**How to show XML file/string stored in BLOB?**

Let's start with, what the problem was:

1. Data in BLOB was a XML file.
2. When selected in query, got:

   [image]
3. When casted, like:

`select CAST(BLOBCOLUMN as VARCHAR(1000)) from TABLE where id  =  100;`

output was in HEX:

[image]

1. Nothing worked... Not even the solution from the links in this topic. 
   !NOTHING!

***By mistake found a solution:***

1. CREATE FUNCTION in DB2:

   `CREATE FUNCTION unhex(in VARCHAR(32000) FOR BIT DATA)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(32000) 
   LANGUAGE SQL
   CONTAINS SQL
   DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
   BEGIN ATOMIC
   RETURN in;
   END`
2. Run SELECT:

   `select UNHEX( CAST(BLOBCOLUMN as VARCHAR(32000) FOR BIT DATA)) from TABLE where id  =  100;`
3. Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use this to convert FOR BIT DATA to characters:

```sql
cast (colvalue as varchar(2000) ccsid ebcdic for sbcs data)
```