# How to cast hex data string to a string db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, rpgle

How would you decode a hex string to get the value in text format by using a select statement?

**For example my data in hex is:**

```
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
```

I want to decode it to get the string value using a select statement.
The value of the above is "ONLY FOR BACK-UP ON LEVEL ONE FOR CRANES"

what I have tried is :

```
    SELECT CAST('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' 
    AS VARCHAR(30000) CCSID 37) from myschema.atable
```

The above sql returns the exact same hex string and not the decoded text string of "ONLY FOR BACK-UP ON LEVEL ONE FOR CRANES" what I expected.

Is it possible to do this with a cast? If it is what will the syntax be?

My problem that I have is a system stores text data in a blob field and I want to use a select statement to see what the text data is in the blob field.

Db : Db2 on Ibm

**Edit:**

I have managed to covert the string to the hex value by using :

```
    select hex(cast('ONLY FOR BACK-UP ON LEVEL ONE FOR CRANES' as varchar(100) ccsid 1208))
FROM myschema.atable
```

This gives me the string in hex :

```
4F4E4C5920464F52204241434B2D5550204F4E204C4556454C204F4E4520464F52204352414E4553
```

Now somehow I need to do the inverse and get the value.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Using the answer from Daniel Lema, I tried using the unhex function but my result that I got was :

```
|+<ßã|êâ ä.í&|+<áîá<|+áã|êäê +áë
```

Is this something to do with a CSSID? Or how should I convet the above to a readable string?

This is the table field definition if it will help the field with my data in is GDTXFT  a  BLOB :

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible what do y want, you want to transform an ASCII or EBCDIC value into a corresponding CHAR Value, and SQL can only transform a Type, not translate it...

Comment: yes I want the ASCII  value, so what you are saying you should create a function to do this?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you need a function, but wait someone else, maybe there's another way

Comment: There's a popular answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913300/convert-hex-value-to-char-on-db2 which looks to be managing to do this via a cast to CHAR (rather than VARCHAR) - have you tried that?

Comment: I don't have db2 for i at hand, but have you tried `select varchar_format(myhexcol) from mytab`? It works for db2 for luw, but with spaces between letters...

Comment: @MandyShaw I tried using CHAR but it gave me the same hex string.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I tried using varchar_format the result was the same hex string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to take your shortened hex string and convert is to a valid EBCDIC string. 
The problem I ran into is that the original hex code you receive comes in UTF-16LE (Thanks Tom Blodget). IBM's CCSID system does not have a distinction between UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE so I am at a loss there on how to convert it properly.

If it is in UTF-8 as you generated later, the following would work for you. It's not the prettiest but throw it in a couple functions and it will work.

```
Create or replace function unpivothex (in_ varchar(30000))
    returns table (Hex_ char(2), Position_ int)
    return
    with returnstring (ST , POS )
    as 
    (Select substring(STR,1,2), 1
    from table(values in_) as A(STR)
    union all
    Select nullif(substring(STR,POS+2,2),'00'), POS+2
    from returnstring, table(values in_) as A(STR)
    where POS+2 <= length(in_)
    )
    Select ST, POS 
    from returnstring
    ;
```

```
Create or replace function converthextostring
   (in_string char(30000))
   returns varchar(30000)
   return
   (select listagg(char(varbinary_format(B.Hex_),1)) within group(order by In_table.Position_)
   from table(unpivothex(upper(in_string))) in_table
   join table(unpivothex(hex(cast('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' as char(53) CCSID 1208)))) A on In_table.Hex_ = A.Hex_
   join table(unpivothex(hex(cast('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' as char(53) CCSID 37)))) B on A.Position_ = B.Position_
   );
```

Here is a version if you're not on at least V7R2 TR6 or V7R3 TR2.

```
Create or replace function converthextostring
   (in_string char(30000))
   returns varchar(30000)
   return
   (select xmlserialize(
             xmlagg(
               xmltext(cast(char(varbinary_format(B.Hex_),1) as char(1) CCSID 37)) 
             order by In_table.Position_) 
           as varchar(30000))
   from table(unpivothex(upper(in_string))) in_table
   join table(unpivothex(hex(cast('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' as char(53) CCSID 1208)))) A on In_table.Hex_ = A.Hex_
   join table(unpivothex(hex(cast('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' as char(53) CCSID 37)))) B on A.Position_ = B.Position_
   );
```

Comment: Thanks for the functions, I am trying to implement them, the first function compiles and gets created, but "converthextostring" is givving me syntax issues with the "group" statement,    "SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -199
Message: [SQL0199] Keyword GROUP not expected. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO. Cause . . . . . :   The keyword GROUP was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword GROUP"     Any ideas how to fix it or a different way to write this?

Comment: Which version of IBMi are you running? I can check the listagg functionality for your version. Latest version is V7R3.

Comment: listagg was released for V7R2 TR6 or V7R3 TR2. Unfortunately, V7R1 is no longer supported by IBM. I've updated my answer though for an alternative to listagg.

Comment: @renier, I've made some changes to handle the UTF-16LE problem from your original question as the prior version did not account for it. Of course this will only work if your messages only contain upper and lower case A-Z. If you want to add numbers, just include them in the second function's list.

Comment: Thank you I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following solution I found published by Marcin Rudzki at [Convert HEX value to CHAR on DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913300/convert-hex-value-to-char-on-db2), tested in my own Db2 for LUW v11 with a small modification.

the solution consists on creating a function just as Marcin suggested:

```
CREATE FUNCTION unhex(in VARCHAR(32000) FOR BIT DATA)
RETURNS VARCHAR(32000) 
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN ATOMIC
RETURN in;
END
```

To test the solution, lets create an HEXSAMPLE table with a HEXSTRING column  loaded with the string representation of a HEX sequence:

```
INSERT INTO HEXSAMPLE (HEXSTRING) VALUES ('4F4E4C5920464F52204241434B2D5550204F4E204C4556454C204F4E4520464F52204352414E4553')
```

Then exec the following query (and here it is different from the original proposal):

```
SELECT UNHEX(CAST(HEXTORAW(HEXSTRING) AS VARCHAR(2000) FOR BIT DATA)) as TEXT, HEXSTRING FROM HEXSAMPLE
```

With result:

```
 TEXT                                           HEXSTRING
 ----------------------------------------   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ONLY FOR BACK-UP ON LEVEL ONE FOR CRANES   4F4E4C5920464F52204241434B2D5550204F4E204C4556454C204F4E4520464F52204352414E4553
```

I hope someone else can find a more direct solution.  Also, if someone can explain why it works, it will be very interesting.

Comment: I tried using the function but I get a different result than you please check my edit update to my question.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't realize that you were working on DB2 for IBM i.  I have some ideas but I don't have an IBM i at hand to try before answering, so, this time I pass.
By the way: HEXTORAW is not documented on IBM i Knowledge Center, so, probably it is not officially supported (yet).

Comment: I am using DB2 on i and had a problem like this. We have a legacy DB where a column is declared as char(3) but the (RPG) programmer uses it to store 24 flags using the bits. This is easy to read (JDBC) using 'hex(flags)' - the Java program receives it as a String 6 long with hex digits. Writing was a problem. The x'ABCDEF' solution above works great, but I couldn't find a way to get that to work with a prepared statement (Spring data JPA). Eventually I found that 'cast(hextoraw(:hexval) as char(3))' worked. hextoraw appears in DB2 10.5 and Db2 for i SQL 7.3 manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I question why you need to do this...

There's valid reasons to convert a hex string back to it's character equivalent...for instance somebody sends you a 32 byte string UUID and you want it back it it's 16 byte binary form.

But there's no reason `ONLY FOR BACK-UP ON LEVEL ONE FOR CRANES` should have been transformed to hex.

I suspect you need to post a new question asking why you're not getting readable strings in the first place.

However, in answer to this question... IBM i has an MI function [Convert Character to Hex (CVTCH)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzatk/CVTCH.htm) that is easily called from any ILE langage.  You could wrap that function call up into a user defined function in order to use it from SQL.

Note that you'll need to know what the hex string represents, EBCDIC, ASCII or Unicode, because you'll need to be able to tell the system what you've started with.  From there there are ways to convert between encoding.

Here's an article that shows how to call the MI function from RPG.
[Utilizing MI Functions in RPG Programs](http://ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/developer/rpg/utilizing-mi-functions-in-rpg-programs/)

A more modern free form version of the prototype that takes advantage of enhancements to the CCSID keyword might look like

```
dcl-pr FromHex extproc('cvtch');
  charString char(32767) ccsid(*UTF8) options(*varsize);
  hexString  char(65534) ccsid(*HEX) const options(*varsize);
  hexStringLen int(10) value;
end-pr;
```

With the above prototype, the system will treat the character string that comes back as UTF8 (ccsid 1208).  But all I'm doing is telling the system how to interpret the bytes that come back.  If the string was actually EBCDIC, I'm going to get garbage.

<strike>I think you could even defined the `cvtch` function directly as an external UDF without needing an ILE wrapper.  I'd have to play around with that...</strike>

Disregard that idea...cvtch only has parameters, not a return value.  Using an ILE wrapper is the best way to move the output parameter to a return value for use as a UDF.

Comment: Thanks, will try to give this a go, I have updated my question to show you the table fields and types, the type is actually a blob and I get the hex string when I do a select from the table. please see edit update. Maybe I am doing this wrong... I am not in control with regards to the system inserting the data I am just trying to create a report to display the content(text) that is stored in the field.

Comment: I would like to know how to call the cvtch fcuntion in a UDF without a ILE wrapper, if you get time I would appreciate it, I will also be trying to figure it out.

Comment: In what library will CVTCH be in? I am assuming I need to specify where CVTCH  is in the UDF

Comment: cvtch is actually an MI builtin, all you need is `extproc('cvtch')` and the compilers will be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your original string is in ASCII format (actually with x'00' byte after each letter), and you have to convert it to EBCDIC.
Below is the solution for latin capital letters only:

```
select cast(translate(replace(mycol, x'00', x'')  
, x'C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E940'  
, x'4142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F505152535455565758595A20'
) as varchar(500) ccsid 37)
from mytab;
```

Every ASCII character is translated to the corresponding EBCDIC one.
x'00' symbols are removed.

Comment: " x'00' byte after each letter" would strongly suggest that the encoding is UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 0):

```
cast (col_name as varchar(2000) ccsid ascii for sbcs data)
```